# Need help again altering output of script

Tags: linux, shell

```
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
| grep PlayerCount \
| head -1l \
| sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
| sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%m\/%d\/%Y %H:%m:%S')/" \
| cut -d">" -f 3,4 \
| sed 's/<\/span>//' \
| awk '{print $3, $4, $1, $2}'
```

Will output:

```
03/19/2012 18:03:58 123,822 people
```

Would anyone be able to help me rewrite this so the output looks like:

```
03/19/2012 18:03:58,123822,people
```

I need it this way because when I import it into googledocs, everything with a comma gets separated. Thanks if you help!

Comment: Um, I'm pretty sure you can replace all that with a single awk script...

Comment: See awk manual for [printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html#Printf-Examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
| grep PlayerCount \
| head -1l \
| sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
| sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%m\/%d\/%Y %H:%m:%S')/" \
| cut -d">" -f 3,4 \
| sed 's/<\/span>//' \
| sed 's/,//' \
| awk '{printf "%s %s,%s,%s\n", $3, $4, $1, $2}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null | perl -le 'use POSIX qw(strftime); while(<>) { if (/PlayerCount.*?(\d*),(\d*).*?currently.*/) { print strftime ("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime) . ",$1$2,people"} }'
```